# Cambiar un valor tipo int a uno tipo string PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Hago una consulta a la BD y obtengo el valor "mes" de los registros de la tabla que es tipo entero.

Quiero que de acuerdo al mes recibido, PHP lo imprima en su forma string. p.e. (mes=1 entonces lo imprima como mes="Enero").

Acá les dejo el código:

```
$peticion="SELECT * FROM operaciones WHERE anio='2016' AND suc_numerosede='1'";
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,$peticion);
$i=1;
while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
  echo $mes[$i]=$fila['mes'].'<br />';
  $i++;
}
```

Esto es porque deseo imprimir los registros mensuales, pero que los meses aparezcan string y no como enteros.

Comment: Una cosa que debes tener claro, y por tu pregunta parece que no lo tienes es que el String (que citas tu) del numero 1 es "1" y en ningún caso será Enero! Tendras que tener una funcion intermedia que te devuelva el nombre del mes de acuerdo al numero indicado resultante de tu consulta.

Comment: @jolsalazar perdon por no explicar bien el planteamiento. Sin embargo mi confusión no era respecto a los tipos de datos (lo tengo claro) sino a esa función necesaria para hacer la conversión.

Comment: Claro, pero lo indicas en tu descripción "Quiero que de acuerdo al mes recibido, PHP lo imprima en su forma string. p.e. (mes=1 entonces lo imprima como mes="Enero"). ". Por eso mi comentario.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
<?php

function nombreMes($mes){
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');  
 $nombre=strftime("%B",mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, 2000)); 
 return $nombre;
} 

while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
  $mes = nombreMes($fila['mes']);
  echo $mes.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola User, no deberias poner codigo solo. explica que tiene mal en su planteamiento y como funciona tu solucion. Un saludo

Comment: No tiene mal nada. Él pidió la manera de imprimir el nombre del mes en base a su número. Él no tiene ese código implementado. Él no tiene errores.

Comment: Da igual que no tenga nada mal, has de explicar por que tu codigo hace lo que el necesita. no puedes plantarlo y ya...

Comment: @user2930137 gracias. a pesar de no haber explicado el codigo me ha sido de ayuda.

Comment: La línea importante es esta: $nombre=strftime("%B",mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, 2000)); 
Puedes leerte la documentación en: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php

Comment: El tema no es solo encontrar la solucion, es tener publicaciones de calidad. Poder puedes hacer muchas cosas pero no significa que debas ... no es una buena filosofia de vida .

Comment: Lo mejores que es la mejor respuesta y la útil y le quitan puntos hahaha. Es buena referencia para las personas con la misma duda. Mi respuesta resuelve el problema del que pregunta y es lo único que debe de importar. Pero bueno, resolví la situación del que pregunta de la mejor forma y los demás no. Cuando el que abra un nuevo foro haga literalmente una pregunta ésta será contestada. Este caso no lo fue, él solo quería una forma de obtener el nombre del mes en base a su número y la obtuvo.

Comment: User, tu repuesta si da la solucion pero no es la mejor respuesta. Mira la [respuesta de A.Cedano](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/52738/15855). Está bien estructurada, con su explicacion y formato. No solo codigo. Repito: aqui no solo se busca una solucion, se buscan posts te calidad.

Answer (score 3):

Define una función:

```
 function getMes($n) {
     if ($n==1) return "enero";
     if ($n==2) return "febrero";
     if ($n==3) return "marzo";
     if ($n==4) return "abril";
     if ($n==5) return "mayo";
     if ($n==6) return "junio";
     if ($n==7) return "julio";
     if ($n==8) return "agosto";
     if ($n==9) return "septiembre";
     if ($n==10) return "octubre";
     if ($n==11) return "noviembre";
     if ($n==12) return "diciembre";
 }
```

otra alternativa a esa función:

```
 function getMes($n) {
     $meses = array("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio"
     "agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre");
     return $meses[$n-1];
 }
```

y cuando imprimas:

```
echo getMes($fila['mes']).'<br />';
```

Comment: if ( n = 1)  o if ( n == 1) ?

Comment: @IranhCanulMay cierto, corregido. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Si se conoce el valor numérico de la fecha, otra forma de hacerlo es usando el método [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)de la clase `DateTime` .

Por ejemplo si el mes=3...

```
$mes_num  = 3;
echo nombre_mes($mes_num);
```

Sólo habría que llamar la función `nombre_mes()` dentro del bucle, pasándole como parámetro el número de mes recuperado de la BD.

```
function nombre_mes($mes_num){

   $obj_fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $mes_num,new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
   $mes_letra=$obj_fecha->format('F');
   return $mes_letra;
}
```

[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5qyg-m1rc)

**Otra forma de hacerlo:**
Combinando las funciones [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) y [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mktime.php):

```
$mes_num  = 6;
$mes_nombre = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_num, 10)); // Junio
```

**Explicación de la función:**

- `!m`, estamos reiniciando el campo mes a la Época Unix (ver enlace de createFromFormat más arriba).
- `F` para obtener el nombre completo del mes (si lo cambiamos por `M`mostrará sólo las tres primeras letras del mismo.

---

**NOTA:**

> Atención, tu consulta es susceptible de [inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php). Se
>   recomienda usar consultas preparadas siempre.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con **[strval()](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/strval.php)**

Ejemplo:

```
$items = strval($var); // $items === "5";
```

Comment: En realidad esta es la mejor respuesta, ya que la pregunta es muy extraña...

Answer (score 1):

El acercamiento más directo a esto es mediante [operaciones ternarias](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) anidadas:

```
while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
  $strMes = 1 == $fila['mes'] ? "enero" : 2 == $fila['mes'] ? "febrero" : 3 == $fila['mes'] ? "marzo" : 4 == $fila['mes'] ? "abril" : 5 == $fila['mes'] ? "mayo" : 6 == $fila['mes'] ? "junio" : 7 == $fila['mes'] ? "julio" : 8 == $fila['mes'] ? "agosto" : 9 == $fila['mes'] ? "septiembre" : 10 == $fila['mes'] ? "octubre" : 11 == $fila['mes'] ? "noviembre" : "diciembre";
  echo $strMes.'<br />';
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Precisamente la [documentación de php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) recomienda no hacer eso. **Nota:** _Es recomendable evitar el "apilamiento" expresiones ternarias. El comportamiento de PHP al utilizar más de un operador ternario en una única sentencia no es evidente_

Answer (score 1):

```
$mes = date ("F",1);
print_r($mes); // January
```

Tan simple como esto.

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
 echo strftime("%B",1); //Enero
```

> Nota:
>    En Windows, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') establece los 
>    nombres del localismo desde la configuración regional o del lenguaje del sistema
>   (accesible por medio del Panel de Control).

[Fuente](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php)

[Otra fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635303/get-day-from-string-in-spanish-php)